# Response string value changing to Integer value after saving it in Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I am facing a weired issue I am getting below response string from server

Server Response ==

```
{"status":1,"userId":"501600688052021","mobile":" 916236365"}
```

But when I save this to Dictionary few of the string values are getting converted to Integer.As shown below "userId" val is integer now and mobile value is string which is retained.

```
Response dictionary formed is ={
    userId = 501600688052021;
    mobile = " 916236365";
    status = 1;
}
```

**Below is the code**

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 NSData *data = [paramString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   [request setHTTPBody:data];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
     NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Server Response ==%@", resSrt);

    if(resSrt.length)
    {

        responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:resSrt options:0 error:&err];

        NSLog(@"Response dictionary formed is =%@", responseDictionary);
    }
```

Comment: The log output doesn't mean they're integers.  NSDictionary's description method doesn't always put quotes around strings.

Comment: Check the class of the object: `[responseDictionary[@"userId"] class]`? In `NSDictionary`, there is only objects, so it's either a `NSString` or a `NSNumber`.